# 'Max' Responsive Breakpoints in em

Tags: css, sass, responsive-design, breakpoints

I'm working on a responsive site using media queries in em, based around Bootstrap 3, using SASS.

The 'max' breakpoints are set on the basis of a browser baseline of 16px. I understand that media queries are based of the browser's base font size which is independent of any base font size set on the document. I've found articles explaining this, recommending em for 'min' breakpoints but can't find any mention for 'max'.

Is there a best practice for setting max breakpoints to take into account a scenario where the browser's baseline isn't 16px?

I'm currently using the following:

```
$screen-xs:                  30em !default;
$screen-xs-min:              $screen-xs !default;
$screen-phone:               $screen-xs-min !default;

$screen-sm:                  48em !default;
$screen-sm-min:              $screen-sm !default;
$screen-tablet:              $screen-sm-min !default;

$screen-md:                  62em !default;
$screen-md-min:              $screen-md !default;
$screen-desktop:             $screen-md-min !default;

$screen-lg:                  75em !default;
$screen-lg-min:              $screen-lg !default;
$screen-lg-desktop:          $screen-lg-min !default;

$screen-xs-max:              ($screen-sm-min - (1 / 16)) !default;
$screen-sm-max:              ($screen-md-min - (1 / 16)) !default;
$screen-md-max:              ($screen-lg-min - (1 / 16)) !default;
```

This is fine assuming the browser's base font size is 16px but $screen-**-max will no longer be valid if the browser's base font size is anything other than 16px.

Comment: You can NEVER EVER assume that the base font-size is 16px.  What's the point in working with ems if you're always performing the mental calculation that 1em = 16px.  You may as well be using px at that point.  You're supposed to be choosing your break points based on the *content*, not some arbitrary common screen size.

Comment: @cimmanon I understand that but this doesn't really answer the question - regardless of where I'm picking breakpoints, to target that specific breakpoint there will be a min and a max point. The max point should be the min of the next breakpoint minus ~1 pixel. So what I'm asking is how can I calculate the max breakpoint without having to rely on the assumption of a 16px base font size?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to get the actual viewport root em size in pixels using only CSS, and neither am I great with frontend. But here's something that you could try:

```
$em-base:           1em
$px:                rem($em-base/16)
$px-relative:       em($em-base/16)
$display-threshold: 800*$px

=small-screens
    @media screen and (max-width: $display-threshold*0.6)
        @content

=medium-screens
    @media screen and (min-width: $display-threshold*0.6+0.001) and (max-width: $display-threshold)
        @content

=large-screens
    @media screen and (min-width: $display-threshold+0.001)
        @content
```

I am guessing you want to calculate your breakpoints based to the root em size. I am testing something similar with my very simple layout which is one pile of blog text in the middle, and this works okay with my requirements.

The idea is to design with 16px as root em size. hence $px is `/16`. But still allow the design to break relatively as all other element sizes, spaces, etc are calculated relatively with the help of modular scale.

As @cimmanon said, the threshold should be decided based on your content though. But also if I make the threshold a fixed amount of pixels, it will become disproportional.

I may be completely wrong though, and would appreciate some comments on the approach as well!